# HTML5 video background in Div - need help resizing to window size

Tags: css, html, video, background

I've been working on this all day but even with all my googling, I haven't figured it out.

Basically I would like to have the same effect as on www.tesla.com

The video is fullsize, but resizes according to the size of the window, and at the same time crops it a bit but keeps the video centered (try it out on Tesla website it's great). If it gets too small, it displays an image instead (for mobile).

I'm running the site on a jekyll theme with GitHub pages : https://alanlemoine.github.io/personal

**My issues:**

- On my 13" screen, the video is too big and a vertical scroll bar
  appears. I would like to have it fit the window, without scroll bars.
  Even if it crops the video at the bottom (something with "overflow:
  hidden" I think ?)
- When resizing the window, the whole video is resized. I would like to
  have it resized like [www.tesla.com](http://www.tesla.com) where it crops it but keeps
  it centered.
- I don't want the video to be completely fullscreen. I need the
  navigation bar at the top. So in a DIV is better.

Can you help ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Here is what I have:

```css
/* Default hide the video on all devices */

#video {
  display: none
}


/* Default display the image to replace the video on all devices */

#videosubstitute {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #video {
    display: block
  }
  #videosubstitute {
    display: none
  }
}

#videoDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
}

#videoBlock,
#videoMessage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
}

#videoMessage {
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: 0;
}

#videoMessage {
  color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}

#videoMessage h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoDiv">
  <div id="videoBlock">
    <div><img src="http://www.imi21.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/t12.jpg" id="videosubstitute" alt="" width="800"></div>
    <video preload="preload" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
    <div id="videoMessage">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively simple trick you can do with HTML 5 and some CSS.

First off you will need to absolutely position your video element, and hide its overflow. Then you will make it 100% the width and height of the page.

Next you will basically stretch the video to crop it based on the aspect ratio of the screen. There is a nifty thing called object-fit, which you can also just write as object-fit:cover which will give you the same effect, but it is not yet supported by IE so you will need both if you decide to use that.

I have included a codepen with a solution for you. 
http://codepen.io/DrkDevil/pen/OpXxZV/

```
<nav>your navigation goes here.</nav>
<div class="flexCon" >
  <div id="videoMessage">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="videoBg">
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<style>
#videoBg { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;}
#videoBg > video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) { #videoBg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) { #videoBg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }}
@supports (object-fit: cover) {#videoBg > video { top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }}

/* Demo  Classes */
nav { position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; left:0; padding:20px; background:#fff; z-index:2;}
/* Center content with flexbox container */
.flexCon { height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
/* Position the content relative to the flex container  */
#videoMessage { z-index:1; position:relative; }
</style>
```

Here is a really good explination of how you can achieve what you are looking for in a more in-depth.

https://fvsch.com/code/video-background/

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much for your answer. I have implemented into the code. As you can see : alanlemoine.github.io/personal it works great, but the video takes the whole screen and overlaps under the nav bar... Is there any CSS trick that could fix it ?

Comment: I looked at the site. It looks great. Not sure what you are asking. You could try and give your navbar a background color or change the font color if you feel that you cant see it very well. Also could you mark the answer above as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you add a nice gradient on the body with something like this.
    
http://codepen.io/DrkDevil/pen/aJGVoW

Comment: I use this site a lot to quickly generate css gradients. it is very useful.
http://www.cssmatic.com/